# controlling multiple cc2541 modules

Tags: android, ios, rgb, bluetooth-lowenergy

can 5 or more ble modules (cc2241), each with an rgb led, be simultaneously controlled at same time from one app.I want to choose and control, at the same time,the rgb led blinking patterns from an ios/android app, so if i press a color on app, all the ble modules will respond at same time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: the main question is .. can multple ble modules be cotrolled at the same ti me

Answer (score 0):

At the *exact* same time is not possible: your central only has one radio PHY, it can only talk to one peripheral at the same time. Connection events with peripherals are scheduled by the Central PHY in a round-robin manner.

If you accept some delay between deliveries of updates to the 5 modules, this is doable.

Let's suppose the 5 modules are connected with equivalent connection parameters, when your application writes the characteristic for each device, phy actually has to wait for the next connection event to actually deliver the packet, in turn for each connection.

In an ideal environment, you could assume worst case latency is (ConnectionInterval * (SlaveLatency + 1)), with some packet loss, this can easily be multiplied by 2 to 5.  ConnectionInterval and SlaveLatency are parameters set by your device.

Let's say all modules should be updated within 200ms allowing one connection event to be lost, you should have a connectionInterval under 100ms and slaveLatency = 0. This is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you, 200ms is no prob. i was not expecting for instant response

Comment: would the response be the same if it was an rf remote control system instead of ble?

Comment: If you mean custom protocol, it could be different: you could design this protocol to broadcast a single packet to control the 5 modules. You'll still need some sort of acknowledgement to work around radio glitches.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you are using Broadcast/Observer connectionless model.

This is exactly the same way how Apple iBeacon works.

In this mode all data is transmitted in advertisement packet of broadcasting device. If you take look on TI CC254x examples you will find few implementations that uses it.

Depending of your application this could be perfectly OK way to go.